# Disable node listings on taxonomy term pages per vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9, panels

I have two vocabularies and I'm trying to hide/disable the node listings that automatically appear on the taxonomy term pages (/taxonomy/term/%), only for one of these vocabularies.

I'm not sure if panels with page manager is the solution, but I don't understand how to make them produce the result I want.

Comment: Possibly https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

Comment: You can use rabbit hole and TVI